# What's wrong with this division?

Tags: java, floating-point

Here's the code:

```
class testsum
{ 
    public static void main(String arg[]) 
    {
        double sum=0; 
        double fraction;
        fraction=-1/9;
        System.out.println("fraction: "+fraction); 
        fraction=-1; 
        fraction=fraction/9; 
        System.out.println("fraction: "+fraction); 
    } 
}
```

the outputs are `0` and then `-0.11111111`

why was the first output `0` and not `-0.11111111111`?

Comment: Dude... this question is 4 years old.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's doing integer division in the first example as this is the default type for a numeric literal.  Try changing it to `-1.0/9` (or `1d/9d` - the d suffix indicates a `double`) and you should get the same answer.

Comment: so it does integer division even though the value is going to be stored in a variable of type double?

Comment: The division happens before it knows it's going to be a double. It does the division in integer, and then realizes it has to be converted to a double. This has been the source of many bugs since epoch.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't take that into account (rightly or wrongly!)

Answer (score 2):

1 and 9 are both integer. Try

```
1.0/9
```

This is why it works for `fraction/9`, since `fraction` is a double.

Answer (score 1):

When you do -1/9, it says "-1, that's an int. 9, that's an int. -1 / 9 in integer division is 0. Oh, now I need to cast to double."

Changing it to -1.0 / 9 should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the "-1/9" in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is 0 because it is doing integer division. -1 and 9 and integers and when divided equal 0. The result is then converted into a double so it can be stored in `fraction`. The easiest solution is this:

```
fraction = -1.0/9;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `-1` and `9` are integers, so `-1/9` is an integer division (with the result `0`, which when cast to double is `0.0`).

To do a floating point division, you should convert one of the numbers to double, `(double) 9`, `9d` or simply `9.0`.

In the latter case, `fraction` is already double (`-1.0`) so `fraction/9` is a floating point division.